# unescape a string

Tags: java, android

I've looked everywhere, it seems this would be common, and simple.  I have a string from a database, "Ros%E9"  What is the simplest way to convert it to "Rose" with an accented e?

Answer (score 12):

Use Java's [URLDecoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) class.

Code sample:

```
String rose = URLDecoder.decode("Rose%E9", "UTF-8");
```